# imageantialias call to undefined function error with gd installed

Tags: php, gd

It's probably best I like to a previous post of mine last month.

[imageantialias call to undefined function error with GD installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756144/imageantialias-call-to-undefined-function-error-with-gd-installed/5939017#5939017)

I am still having problems with this, could anyone help?

I have contacted my hosting provider who says that to do a php recompile I need to upgrade to a dedicated server. Is this correct?

Thanks,
James.

Comment: Well, you still should give answer to @markus, do you have root access to your server?

Comment: I've lost my old username pass so I had to create a new account.

Answer (score 2):

As I said already in a comment in your other question. If you're on a shared hosting, you have to accept the decision of the hosting company not to recompile PHP. If they would recompile PHP for every user sharing that hosting, they'd be recompiling all the time and probably create trouble for other users on the hosting.

What you need is a VPS hosting, it's much more convenient anyways. Try [ServerGrove](http://www.servergrove.com), the coolest hosting I've ever used. They have VPS hostings for all PHP needs.

Comment: Thanks, i'll speak to the client about switching to a VPS. If they agree then i'll probably need a little help recompiling. Thanks for your help markus!