# How to do a PHP Recompile? Imagecreatetruecolor error

Tags: php, gd, recompile

As this is a new question I assume it's fine to create a new fresh question?

My previous question is here:

[imageantialias call to undefined function error with GD installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756144/imageantialias-call-to-undefined-function-error-with-gd-installed)

Markus helped me figure out the problem, I have since contacted the clients and set up a VPS for them, I have transferred the files and database and everything is running fine. Apart from the same error, only this time, I'm getting a different error;

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor() in /home/public_html/admin/library/functions.php on line 232
```

I assume this is relating to the same thing and it required a php recompile? Could someone please give me some instructions on how to do a php recompile on Mac OS X, I tried the PHP docs but I can't seem to understand how it works.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct version of PHP and GD installed.  From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php):

> Depending on your PHP and GD versions
>   this function is defined or not. With
>   PHP 4.0.6 through 4.1.x this function
>   always exists if the GD module is
>   loaded, but **calling it without GD2
>   being installed PHP will issue a fatal
>   error and exit**. With PHP 4.2.x this
>   behaviour is different in issuing a
>   warning instead of an error. Other
>   versions only define this function, if
>   the correct GD version is installed.