# Capctha creation code in PHP not working

Tags: php, captcha

I'm trying to make a captcha in php. This is my code:

```
$amountChars = 5;
$randString = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, $amountChars);
$img = imagecreatfromjpeg("noise.jpg");
imageantialias($img, true);

$x = 20;
$y = 35;
$deltaX = 40;

for($i = 0; $i < $amountChars; $i++){
    $size = rand(18, 28);
    $r = rand(0,152);
    $g = rand(0,152);
    $b = rand(0,152);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);
    $angle = -30 + rand(0, 60);
    imagettftext($img, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, "Blokletters-Balpen.ttf", $randString{$i});
    $x += $deltaX;
}

header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagePNG($img);
```

Problem is, that it does not work. I'm searching a mistake over an hour, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Please explain what is not working. (And how much a dinar is)

Comment: images need to get rendered on their own page.

Comment: Why are you mixing PNG and JPEG ? (imagecreatefromjpeg, and later imagePNG) Are you sure that is allowed? If not, have you tried converting your base image to a PNG and use imagecreatefrompng ?

Comment: **Placeholders_in_use**
<img src="image_capcha.php" />
I have...

**nl-x**
image doesn't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this again since I got flamed for not giving a real answer... Walking through your code step by step I was able to get it running with the following modifications:

```
$amountChars = 5;
$randString = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, $amountChars);
// TYPO: MISSING E
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("noise.jpg");

// IT'S POSSIBLE THIS FUNCTION ISN'T DEFINED:
// SEE REFERENCE LINK BELOW CODE
// imageantialias($img, true);

$x = 20;
$y = 35;
$deltaX = 40;

for($i = 0; $i < $amountChars; $i++) {
    $size = rand(18, 28);
    $r = rand(0,152);
    $g = rand(0,152);
    $b = rand(0,152);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);
    $angle = -30 + rand(0, 60);
    // ADDED ./ TO FONT PATH, CHANGED $randString{$i} TO $randString[$i]
    imagettftext($img, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, "./Blokletters-Balpen.ttf", $randString[$i]);
    // WHY IS THIS HERE?
    $x += $deltaX;
}
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagePNG($img);
```

The `imageantialias` function [doesn't appear to be available on all systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756144/imageantialias-call-to-undefined-function-error-with-gd-installed). It wasn't available on mine, so I just commented it out.

Those changes should at least get your code working. If you're looking for a more in depth example, I recommend you review [this tutorial](http://inboudayo.blogspot.com/2014/02/captcha-image-using-gd-library.html).

Answer (score -1):

I took your code, created a `noise.jpg` images and even downloaded [`Blokletters-Balpen.ttf`](http://www.dafont.com/blokletters.font) from here to see what’s up. A quick look at your code shows a typo:

```
$img = imagecreatfromjpeg("noise.jpg");
```

Shouldn’t that be [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)? Note the missing `e` in your original code:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("noise.jpg");
```

It should work now, I assume? Unless there are issues you are having placing it in `<img src="image_capcha.php" />`?