# PHP GD bundled extension without recompiling PHP - solution

Tags: php, gd, php-extension

The bundled extension offer a lot of functionality. I have spent a lot of time how to compile extension for my version of PHP. So there are instructions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**0,** Install PHP development package. Also You should have installed PHP with GD extension (but not bundled)

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

**1,** Download source code of used PHP (for me 5.6.18)

```
wget http://cz2.php.net/get/php-5.6.18.tar.gz/from/this/mirror -O php-5.6.18.tar.gz
```

**2,** Extract archive

```
tar -xzf php-5.6.18.tar.gz
```

**3,** Go to the source code of GD extension

```
cd php-5.6.18/ext/gd/
```

**4,** Prepare the extension (run **phpize** in that directory)

```
phpize
```

**5,** Now the configure command

**5.1,** The arguments depends on Your linux distribution. My was these:

```
--with-freetype-dir=shared,/usr --with-vpx-dir=shared,/usr --with-jpeg-dir=shared,/usr --with-xpm-dir=shared,/usr/X11R6
```

**5.2,** For getting paths for libraries You must run this command and search only the search arguments, which are specified above (5.1)

```
php-config --configure-options
```

**5.3,** Also add this arguments for configure (the second argument makes bundled version)

```
--with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-gd
```

**6,** Final configure command

```
sudo ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=YOUR_VALUE --with-vpx-dir=YOUR_VALUE --with-jpeg-dir=YOUR_VALUE --with-xpm-dir=YOUR_VALUE
```

**7,** Now run make

```
make
```

**8,** After compiling You should see something like this:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /home/jakub/php-5.6.18/ext/gd/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.
```

So in the directory **modules** You have compiled bundled extension **gd.so**.
9, Replace NOT bundled gd.so by Your new compiled bundled extension, for my version of PHP It was command:

```
sudo cp -f ./gd.so /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so
```

**10,** Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

*Hope this helps!* and will You spend less time than me.

Comment: Thank you @kuba1999 ! Worked like a charm on ubuntu 16.04 with libpng 12 and 16 both installed :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

1. Go to rpmfind.net and search php-gd-bundled for you php version.
2. Extract rpm (rpm2cpio archive_name.rpm | cpio -idmv)
3. Backup your gd.so and then copy gd.so from archive to you php lib directory.

---

Also I could compile a module with the following parameters:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# Created by configure

'./configure' \
'--with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' \
'--with-gd=shared' \
'--with-freetype-dir=/usr' \
'--with-vpx-dir=/usr' \
'--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' \
'--with-xpm-dir=/usr' \
'--with-png-dir=/usr' \
'--with-t1lib=/usr' \
'--enable-gd-native-ttf' \
"$@"
```